# let maxima display an exponentiation as a function instead of a caret

Tags: cas, maxima

maxima accepts both `a^b` and `a**b` as input for exponentiation, and will always output the exponent with caret `^`.

Is it also possible to get the output as a function, like `pow(a,b)`?

Comment: What is your larger goal here? Are you, by chance, trying to generate code for another system (Python, C, something else)? You say that exponents are output with `^` -- do you mean that you are looking at the result of `grind` or `string` or `display2d:false`? Or do you mean that you want to see `pow(a, b)` in whatever user interface you are using? If so, which user interface are you using? Thanks for any information.

Comment: Indeed, we are trying to generate syntax for another system, in this case javascript (where it is Math.pow(a,b) ). We currently use the grind function for output. We do not need pow(a,b) to work in maxima, it's only for the ouput. thanks Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as you said, you want to output `Math.pow(a,b)` for Javascript. The approach I'll suggest here is to replace `a^b` expressions in Maxima with `Math.pow(a,b)` expressions and output that.

```
(%i1) e : sqrt(a) + b^(3/2) + 1/c + exp(d^f);
                              f
                             d    1    3/2
(%o1)                      %e   + - + b    + sqrt(a)
                                  c
(%i2) subst ("^"=lambda([a, b], Math.pow(a, b)), e);
                                         3                  1
(%o2) Math . pow(c, - 1) + Math . pow(b, -) + Math . pow(a, -)
                                         2                  2
                                             + Math . pow(%e, Math . pow(d, f))
```

OK, so that's most of the work there. Some expressions are represented as `"^"` expressions even if they appear to be something else, for example, `sqrt(a)` is `a^(1/2)` and `1/c` is `c^(-1)`. If you need for those to be preserved as `sqrt(a)` and `1/c` then we'll have to work on that.

I'm guessing it's best to have floating point values instead of integer ratios. Also, we'll replace `%e` by its numerical value. If you want `%e^x` to be rendered as `Math.exp(x)`, we can work on that. Or if you want `Math.pow(Math.E, x)`, that's relatively simple; just evaluate `subst(%e = Math.E, <your expression>)`.

```
(%i3) float (%);
(%o3) Math . pow(c, - 1.0) + Math . pow(b, 1.5) + Math . pow(a, 0.5)
                              + Math . pow(2.718281828459045, Math . pow(d, f))
```

Maxima considers `x . y` to mean noncommutative multiplication, but that doesn't come into play here so that's fine. By default it is displayed with a space on either side of the dot, but if you're willing to do a tiny amount of Lisp hacking we can remove the space. (I guess it doesn't matter to Javascript, right? `Math . pow` is equivalent to `Math.pow`, isn't it?)

```
(%i4) :lisp (setf (get 'mnctimes 'dissym) '(#\.))
(.)
(%i4) %o3;
(%o4) Math.pow(c, - 1.0) + Math.pow(b, 1.5) + Math.pow(a, 0.5)
                                  + Math.pow(2.718281828459045, Math.pow(d, f))
```

OK, now we can output the expression.

```
(%i5) grind (%o3);
Math.pow(c,-1.0)+Math.pow(b,1.5)+Math.pow(a,0.5)
                +Math.pow(2.718281828459045,Math.pow(d,f))$
(%o5)                                done
```

Is that the expected output?

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is awesome. For now, I only needed the first part, but the rest is also very interesting!

Comment: Hi Robert. Following up on this, we now would like a way to change %e^(anything) to exp(anything). I saw that maxima has ways of going the other way from exp() to %e^, but is this also possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'll add another answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked about converting `%e^x` to `exp(x)`. That's easy to do, but to make it stick, we have to disable simplification, i.e. the application of identities which Maxima uses to find a general representation of an expression. By default Maxima simplifies `exp(x)` to `%e^x`. We can replace `%e^x` by `exp(x)` but we need to disable simplification to prevent it from going back again.

```
(%i1) simp:false $
(%i2) matchdeclare (xx, all) $
(%i3) defrule (to_exp, %e^xx, Math.exp(xx));
                                   xx
(%o3)                   to_exp : %e   -> Math . exp(xx)
(%i4) apply1 (1 + %e^(x + %e^y), to_exp);
(%o4)                  1 + Math . exp(x + Math . exp(y))
```

Probably you only want to disable simplification (i.e. `simp:false`) when you are ready to output the expression. But I can imagine situations in which you would have it disabled, e.g. if it is important to output the expression exactly the way it was entered, e.g. `x + x` instead of `2*x`.

I've used a different mechanism to do the replacement here, namely `defrule` which defines a pattern matching rule. Pattern matching is very useful, and I encourage you to take a look at `defrule` and `matchdeclare` in the Maxima documentation.